# How to float box of text on the right side without leaving a gap throughout the rest of the document?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

### Problem

I am trying to create a document where a box of text will float on the right side.  The rest of the text within the document should flow around the box.  My searches have lead me to `wrapfigure`, but it doesn't seem to work the way I expected.

In my first example below I use `wrapfigure` without specifying a number of lines and the page doesn't wrap at all.  It essentially creates two columns because there is a large gap for the rest of the document.  The second page isn't showed, but it has a gap the whole way down.

The second example shows the same code except I specify the number of lines on `wrapfigure`.  It only wraps for 3 lines which is what I expect, but it does it for every paragraph in the document.  Again, the second page isn't shown.

I want all text to be the full width of the document except for the areas where the box is.  This seams like it shouldn't be too difficult, but I haven't figured it out yet.

### `wrapfigure` (default number of lines)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage[alpine,misc]{ifsym}
\textheight=9.0in
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2.1in}

\footnotesize
\begin{framed}

\invisiblesection{\textit{Side Bar}}
\subsection*{Side Section A}

\lipsum[1]

\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}

{\Huge Title}\\
\textit{\small subtitle}

\pagebreak[1]
\section*{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-4]

\pagebreak[1]
\section*{Section 2}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

#### Example

[image: Example with default number of lines page 1]

### `wrapfigure` (3 number of lines)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage[alpine,misc]{ifsym}
\textheight=9.0in
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{r}{2.1in}

\footnotesize
\begin{framed}

\invisiblesection{\textit{Side Bar}}
\subsection*{Side Section A}

\lipsum[1]

\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}

{\Huge Title}\\
\textit{\small subtitle}

\pagebreak[1]
\section*{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-4]

\pagebreak[1]
\section*{Section 2}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

#### Example

[image: Example with 3 number of lines page 1]

Comment: Should the box of text b

Comment: Should the box of text have to break across pages?

Comment: In the second example you told wrapfig to leave 3 lines for the figure and then gave it a figure of over 30 lines so it's not surprising that it got confused.

Comment: Sorry if the second example was confusing.  I realize that it won't wrap correctly due to the size differences.  What was unexpected to me was that every single paragraph in the document was doing it.  I would expect the first, maybe all paragraphs that "touch" the floating box, but not the whole document.

Comment: @Bernard, the box of text should be confined to the first page.

Comment: @pgreen2 the underlying parshape mechanism only allows the shape of a _single_ paragraph to be altered. The fact that wrapfig can do multiple paragraphs (by internally re-calculating the required shape for the later paragraphs) is something of a feat, but you should be impressed when it works, not surprised when it doesn't:-) putting headings and lists in the text that is wrapping makes it _much_ more difficult and likely to go wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

wrapfig works best if there is just plain text that is wrapping round the figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage[alpine,misc]{ifsym}
\textheight=9.0in
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}


\begin{document}

\part{Title}
\textit{\small subtitle}


\section*{Section 1}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2.1in}
\vspace{-4cm}
\footnotesize
\begin{framed}

\invisiblesection{\textit{Side Bar}}
\subsection*{Side Section A}

\lipsum[1]

\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-4]


\section*{Section 2}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see where your code is different than mine, but the subtly is lost on me.  Can you better define "just plain text is wrapping the figure" with respect to the change you made?

Comment: @pgreen2 I moved the section headings and pagebreak commands out of that area (and also of course didn't specify that only 3 lines should be indented for teh figure)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this is what you want. It uses the generic macros from `insbox.tex`. This set of macros defines  `\InsertBoxL`  and `\InsertBoxR` commands that allow to insert any kind of ‘box’, and can work when `wrapfig` does not (I recently used it for insertion in a list environment).

Syntax: `\InsertBoxR{number of fullwidth lines before insertion}{inserted box}[optional corrective number of lines]`.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
    %\usepackage[alpine,misc]{ifsym}
    \textheight=9.0in
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
    \sectionmark{#1}}

    \input{insbox}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}

    {\Huge Title}\\
    \textit{\small subtitle}

    \pagebreak[1]
    \section*{Section 1}

    \InsertBoxR{0}{
    \footnotesize\setlength\fboxsep{10pt}\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
    \fcolorbox{IndianRed3}{AntiqueWhite1!30}{\begin{minipage}{2.1in}
    \invisiblesection{\textit{Side Bar}}
    \subsection*{Side Section A}
    %
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}}
    }[10]
    \lipsum[1-4]

    \pagebreak[1]
    \section*{Section 2}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    \end{document}
```

[image]